# Convert String to NSDictionary by ignoring string literal

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsdictionary, string-literals

I'm getting dictionary value from server in form of String. Now when I try to use that String, it contains \ before ".

I get below value from my web service:
`“\”{\\\”111\\\”:\\\”abc\\\”, \\\”222\\\”:\\\”xyz\\\”}\”`

I'm trying to convert this string to NSDictionary. Can you please some one guide me for this. Which is the easiest way to convert this to NSDictionary. My current code is as below, but it's not working

```
var permValue = perm.value?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")
let data = permValue?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
if let dict = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary{
    print("Permission Dictionary : \(dict)")
}
```

I'm getting an error while converting data to  NSDictionary.

Please help. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is that the raw data from a network intercept, or a logged version? Why is the server adding so many escapes?

Comment: It's raw data from the server.

Comment: Then you should probably fix the web service since that data is definitely broken.